# The sum of the square roots of $n$ distinct squarefree integers is never an integer. Elementary proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, integers

I'm trying to prove that, if $k_1, \cdots k_n$ are distinct squarefree integers than
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{k_i} \notin \mathbb{N}
$$
without using the theory of algebraic extensions nor Galois theory. the usual proof is the following:

---

The theorem is true for $n=2$. Assume it is true for $n-1$ squarefree integers, than we have that
$$
[ \mathbb{Q}(k_1, \cdots k_{n-1}) : \mathbb{Q} ]>1 
$$
where $[K :L]$ is the [degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_field_extension) of the field extension. Now assume
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{k_i} \in \mathbb{N}
$$
than
$$
1=[ \mathbb{Q}(k_1, \cdots ,k_{n-1},k_n) : \mathbb{Q} ]=[ \mathbb{Q}(k_1, \cdots ,k_{n-1},k_{n}) : \mathbb{Q}(k_1, \cdots ,k_{n-1} )] [ \mathbb{Q}(k_1, \cdots ,k_{n-1}) : \mathbb{Q} ]
$$
where I have used the [tower lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_field_extension#The_multiplicativity_formula_for_degrees). This is absurd and so the theorem is proved by induction (to be more precise this proves the theorem for any set of integers that are not perfect squares)

**EDIT**

I will give some intuition of the proof that $$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{k_1}, \sum_{i=2}^{n} \sqrt{k_i})=\mathbb{Q}(\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sqrt{k_i})$$

To do this i will use the following particular case of the [primitive element theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem):

*If $a,b$ are algebraic over a field of characteristic $0$ than $F(a,b)=F(c)$ for some $c \in F(a,b)$. Moreover if $f$ is the minimal polynmial of $a$ than $c=a+db$ where $d \in F$ is such that $a+db$ is not a root of $f$ in its splitting field*

As the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{k_1}$ is $x^2-k_1$ we see that, if $\sum_{i=2}^n \sqrt{k_i} \ne \pm 2\sqrt{k_1}$ we can choose $d=1$

I will not give the full proof of this, but the core is to show that, if we call $g$ the minimal polynomial of $b$ and $h(x):= f(a+d(b-x))$ we have
$$
\gcd(g,h)=\gcd_{F(a+db)}(g,h)=x-b
$$

that implies that $b \in F(a+db)$ and so $F(a,b) \subseteq F(a+db)$

---

[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437350/the-sum-of-square-roots-of-non-perfect-squares-is-never-integer) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/396205/sum-of-square-roots-of-natural-numbers) there are other proofs that still uses Galois theory of at least field extensions

*Is there any elementary proof that can be understood by people without knowledge in abstract algebra ?*

The case $n=2$ can be proven by squaring the sum, but already in the case $n=3$ I don't know how to prove it without using field extensions

**Update**

As said in the comments if the integers are pairwise coprime the case $n=3$ can be proved by using only elementary methods indeed by squaring both members of the equation
$$
\sqrt{k_1}+\sqrt{k_2}=N-\sqrt{k_3}
$$
and regrouping all the integer terms we have
$$
2\sqrt{k_1k_2} +2N \sqrt{k_3}=N_2
$$
squaring again both members we arrive to $8N \sqrt{k_1k_2k_3}=N_3$ that is never satisfied for pairwise coprime squarefree integers

Comment: $2n\times 3n\times 6=(6n)^2$ is a perfect square of your type (take $n$ to be square free and prime to $6$).

Comment: @lulu thanks. It was only a necessary condition. Not sufficient

Comment: pairwise coprime squarefree means the product is not a square;  let's see what your recent edit did.....  actually pairwise coprime and not squares  still says the product is not a square

Comment: @WillJagy it removes a wrong characterization I gave. The pairwise above was a mistake. Should have been "distinct"

Comment: How do you justify your claim that the two conditions
$$
[ \mathbb{Q}(k_1, \cdots k_{n-1}) : \mathbb{Q} ] > 1\\
\sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{k_i} \in \mathbb{N}
$$
together imply 
$$
[ \mathbb{Q}(k_1, \cdots ,k_{n-1},k_n) : \mathbb{Q} ]=1
$$
??

Comment: @quasi $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{k_1}, \cdots, \sqrt{k_n})=\mathbb{Q}(\sum_i^n \sqrt{k_i})=\mathbb{Q}$ if $\sum_i^n \sqrt{k_i} \in \mathbb{N}$. The first one can be proven generalizing [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2446986/show-that-if-sqrta-sqrtb-neq-0-then-mathbbq-sqrta-sqrtb-m)

Comment: The link you refer to in your above comment only deals with the case $n=2$.

Comment: @quasi I added some details. As it is not the core of the question i didn't went in full details

Comment: FWIW I looked into this a long time back. There is a paper with an elementary (but very long) proof, but I don't know how to get to it. It that basically multiplies $( \sqrt{k_1} \pm \sqrt{k_2} \pm \ldots \pm \sqrt{k_n} )$, and makes an inductive argument that is similar to the field-theoretic approach.

Comment: Probably the most elementary way is that [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/136655/242) in the dupe. Be sure to read the linked introductions (for motivation and field theory language). The more general case (linear indepence) is also elementary (but wih a more complex induction).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are my notes from 10 years ago, which might have errors in them. I did not come up with this argument.
I know images aren't ideal, but I'm too lazy to type this up. Feel free to delete/edit/vote this solution as desired.

Note: Since 1 is (considered) a squarefree integer, OP's naive claim that $ \sqrt{ k_i } \not \in \mathbb{N}$ needs to be modified to remove $k_i = 1$.

[image]

(You can ignore the following note about how to use repeated squaring for $n \leq 4$. However, this doesn't extend to more variables.)

[image]

[image]

We're now ready to proof a slight variant of the theorem listed at the start, and is a slightly stronger statement than what OP asked for (as it allows for negative coefficients):

> If $ \{ a_i \}$ are distinct numbers from the set $SF \backslash \{1 \}$, and $\{ b_i\}$ are any integers, then $ S = \sum b_i \sqrt{a_i } \in \mathbb{N}$ if and only if all $ b_i = 0 $ (and hence $ S = 0 $ ).

Motivation: The field theoretic idea here is that if $ S = \sum b_i \sqrt{a_i}$, then for any prime $ p \mid a_1$ replacing $\sqrt{p}$ with $ - \sqrt{p}$ throughout will still retain the validity of the expression. This implies that $ S = -b_1 \sqrt{a_i} + \sum \pm b_i \sqrt{ a_i } $ for a known set of $ \pm b_i$ where the signage depends only on whether $p \mid a_i $. Adding these two expressions, we get $ 2 S $ as the sum of fewer radical terms, so an induction approach could work.
We will merely show the weaker result that $ S = -b_1 \sqrt{a_1} + \sum_{i=2}^n \pm b_i\sqrt{a_i} $ for some suitable choice of signs, which is sufficient to add these expressions and reduce the number of terms.

The backwards part is obvious. We prove the forward part by induction.
Base case: If $ b_1 \sqrt{a_1} = S$ with $b_1 \neq 0$ then $b_1^2 a_1 = S^2$ and so $a_1 $ is a perfect square, which is not possible in $ SF \backslash \{ 1 \}$. Thus $b_1 = 0 $.

Induction step: Suppose it is true for $n-1$ summations.
Case 1: $ S = 0 $.
Multiply throughout by $\sqrt{a_i}$.
Since $a_i \neq a_1$, so $ a_i a_1 = k_i^2 a_i'$ where $a_i' \in SF \backslash \{ 1 \}$.
Thus $\sum_{i=2}^n (b_i k_i) \sqrt{a_i'} = - b_1 a_1 \in \mathbb{N}$.
Applying the induction hypothesis, we get $ b_i' = 0 \Rightarrow b_i = 0 $ for $i = 2$ to $n$, and  $  0 = S = b_1 \sqrt{a_1} \Rightarrow b_1 = 0 $.

Case 2: $ S \neq 0 $.
Set up $F_{L(\sqrt{a_1}, \sqrt{a_2}, \ldots \sqrt{a_n} )} (T) $ from the previous discussion, so $F_{L(\sqrt{a_1}, \sqrt{a_2}, \ldots \sqrt{a_n} )} (S) = 0  $, and

$$ 0 = \sqrt{a_1} P(a_1, a_2, \ldots a_n, S) + Q(a_1, a_2, \ldots , a_n, S).$$

The polynomials $P$ and $Q$ have integer coefficients, so when evaluated at the integers will give us integer values, thus $ 0 = \sqrt{a_1} P^* + Q^*$ and hence these values are also 0. Thus, $ 0 = -\sqrt{a_1} P^* + S^*$.

Now, consider
$$ \begin{array} { r l }
G_L(T) & = \prod [ T + L'(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n) ] \\
& = \prod [ T - L'(-x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n) ] \\
& = -x_1 P(x_1^2, x_2^2, \ldots , x_n^2, T) + Q(x_1^2, x_2^2, \ldots , x_n^2, T). \end{array}  $$

Since $ 0 = - \sqrt{a_1} P^* + Q^* = \prod(S + L')$, so there exists some $S+L^* = 0$.
We have $S = -b_1 \sqrt{a_1} + \sum_{i=2}^{n} c_i \sqrt{a_i}$ where $ c_i \in \{ b_i, -b_i \}$.
Adding up the 2 expressions for $S$, we get that $2S = \sum_{i=2}^n (b_i + c_i) \sqrt{a_i}$ and hence by the induction hypothesis $2S = 0$.
This is a contradiction, so this case cannot occur.

---

Original version of the final part.

[image]

Comment: I completly understand why you don't want to type all this up. If these notes are online a good compromise could be to add the reference, but for me they are fine.

Comment: @Marco **Beware** The argument can't possibly be correct as written since it does not use the  (necessary) hypothesis that the radicands are squarefree. (else e.g. $\, \sqrt 8 - 2\sqrt 2  = 0).\,$ Calvin: please give a *complete, correct* proof (in particular show how to finish the proof).

Comment: I overlooked it. If it can help the mistake is to suppose $M \ne 0$ this surely happen if the radicands are distinct squarefree (in the linked dupe there is the link to the proof of llinearly independence of square-roots), but of course it need to be proven.

Comment: @BillDubuque 1/ For clarity, I added in the statement of the theorem, which requires the $a_i$ to be distinct to avoid trivial cancellations. This wasn't made obvious in the writeup.           2/ The case of $S= 0 $ needs to be dealt with, and was glossed over in the writeup. I've since added details. The requirement of $a_i$ being distinct is used in $a_1 a_i \neq k_i^2$.   $\quad$ I believe that this works now, though let me know if you have any concerns.

Answer (score 0):

Distinct squarefree integers: $a_n$ with n=1..k, now first try:

$\sqrt{a_{1}}+\sqrt{a_{2}}=c$ with $c$ an integer at will.
$\sqrt{a_{2}}=-\sqrt{a_{1}}+c$ then square it:
$a_{2}=-2\sqrt{a_{1}}c+a_{1}+c^2$ -- since $a_1$ is a distinct squarefree integer this is not possible.

Again:
$\sqrt{a_{1}}+\sqrt{a_{2}}+\sqrt{a_{3}}=c$
$\sqrt{a_{2}}+\sqrt{a_{3}}=-\sqrt{a_{1}}+c$
$2\sqrt{a_{3}}\sqrt{a_{2}}+a_{2}+a_{3}=-2\sqrt{a_{1}}c+a_{1}+c^2$ and same on RHS as above -- not possible.

Continue ad libitum.

Comment: Unfortunately, repeated squaring will only work for up to 5 radicals with distinct square-free parts. Past 6, repeated squaring introduces even more radicals, that you cannot fully get rid of.

Comment: You can't continue. If you have $4$ square roots you will end up, after squaring with
$$a_1+a_2+a_3 +2\sqrt{a_1a_2} +2\sqrt{a_1a_3}+2\sqrt{a_2a_3}=a_4+c^2 -2 \sqrt{a_4}$$
Similarly if you  calculate
$$(\sqrt{a_1}+\sqrt{a_2})^2=(c+\sqrt{a_3}+\sqrt{a_4})^2$$ so still $4$ radicals

Comment: As you **can not** get rid of the roots the equation is invalid with integers only. For me it's evident enough to proof _The sum of the square roots of n distinct squarefree integers is never an integer._

Comment: @m-stgt  What you are doing is assuming that a linear combination (over the integers) of radicals is never an integer to prove that the sum of radicals is never an integer. We can't do that

Comment: @Marco -- _We can't do that?_ Then pls explain what's wrong with this contradiction: $a_{2}=-2\sqrt{a_{1}}c+a_{1}+c^2$ Maybe I overlook something, but even the sum of those equations will **with integers** never be possible. Sure, my "insight" is no evidence, fair enough.

Comment: You can do it with a single radical, but you can't do it if there is more than one radical. We don't know if $$2(\sqrt{a_1a_2}+\sqrt{a_1a_3}+\sqrt{a_2a_3}+\sqrt{a_4})$$ is an integer or not. That is basically what we are trying to prove *i.e.* that the sum of radicals is an integer iif the radicals theirself are rational